# Strictly Convex Functions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I am trying to show the equivalence of two definitions of strictly convex functions. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function.

- The function $f$ is strictly convex if for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that (Hess$f$)$_p:=\left[\left.\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\right|_p\right]$ is a positive definite matrix (i.e. is such that $u^T(\text{Hess}f)_pu>0$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$).
- The function $f$ is strictly convex if for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $0< t< 1$ we have that $f((1-t)u+tv)<(1-t)f(u)+tf(v)$.

The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to show that if a strictly convex function has a local minimum then it is in fact a global minimum. I can prove this using the second bullet, but the definition I am working with is the first bullet.

To prove the equivalence I have tried using Taylor's theorem, but I can't get it to work out nicely.

I have also tried using bullet 1 to prove the a local minimum is a global minimum directly, but cant get that to work either.

Comment: No, the second definition is half correct. The use of the strict inequality is the key. However, the OP does need to change $0\leq t\leq 1$ to $0<t<1$. You are right, however, that the implication is only one way: the first implies the second, but the second does not imply the first. Indeed, it is possible to have a strictly convex function that is not differentiable.

Comment: The first definition is not a definition of strict convexity. This is a sufficient condition for $f$ be strictly convex. And it is also a sufficient condition for $f$ to be STRONGLY convex which implies strict convexity.

Comment: You need to restrict $u\neq0$ in your first definition.

Comment: You can use the same approach [as in my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/720259/147263), changing the inequalities to be strict.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will do that!