# Hessian to show convexity - check my approach please

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

I need to check the convexity of $f(x)$ for these two questions, using the Hessian matrix. I am aware the function can be said to be convex if over the domain of $f$ the hessian is defined and is positive semidefinite.

First question: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x_1x_2 & x\in \mathbb{R}^n_+ \\
      +\infty & otherwise
         \end{cases}
$$
then the hessian:
$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

So this has eigenvalues $$\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0 $$
Does this mean the matrix can be called positive-semidefinite? Can we conclude $f(x)$ is convex?

Second question:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{x_1^2}{x_2} & x\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{++} \\
      +\infty & otherwise
         \end{cases}$$

$$H = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{x_2} & \frac{-2x_1}{x_2^2} \\ \frac{-2x_1}{x_2^2} & \frac{2x_1^2}{x_2^3} \end{pmatrix} $$

since $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 >0$ can we conclude $f(x)$ again is convex? I have read my notes and textbooks carefully, but am unsure what specifically is meant by a positive definite matrix, and in regards to question 1, if the eigenvalues are both 0, does this satisfy being positive definite and result in convexity?

Have I approached these questions correctly?

Comment: yes - I have fixed it now, thanks

Comment: You are incorrect about the eigenvalues of $H$ for the first function, which is not convex. Sanity check: the only symmetric matrix with all zero eigenvalues is the all-zeros matrix.

Comment: As for the second function, you have not established what the eigenvalues are. You claim they are positive, but given the mistake in the first instance, skepticism about your second claim is warranted. The truth is that $H$ *is* positive definite over the domain of the function, but this is best proven not with eigenvalues but by examining the matrices' minors, and proving those are positive.

Comment: So its always better to check if the minors are positive than if the eigenvalues are positive to check for positive semi-definiteness ?

Comment: It's better to do what is *easier*. I'd say usually that will be to check the principal minors.

Comment: @diabloescobar, keep in mind that the trick of positive-determinant minors shows strict positive-definiteness only, not positive-semidefiniteness -- indeed, your first example shows a case where all determinants are $0$, but there exists a negative eigenvalue anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This answer addresses the first question.

A real-valued, symmetric matrix is positive-semidefinite if and only if all its eigenvalues are nonnegative -- $0$ counts, no matter how many times it occurs.

Also, positive-semidefiniteness *everywhere* of the Hessian is equivalent to convexity; see [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720259/f-is-convex-function-iff-hessian-matrix-is-nonnegative-definite).  Hessian matrices of real-valued $C^2$ functions are symmetric.  So $0$ eigenvalues do count in this equivalence too; if your computation was correct, then the first function would be convex.

---

However, your first eigenvalue computation is incorrect.  Indeed, we see that

$$H \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = (-1) \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix},$$

so there is an eigenvalue of $-1$.  Also, there is an eigenvalue of $1$, since

$$H \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Since the number of eigenvalues is less than or equal to the dimension, we have eigenvalues of $\pm 1$.

[How did I magically create these eigenvectors? Well, I saw that $H^2 = I$, so I figured the constants were nice, and since the matrix looks like a reflection over the axis $x_1 = x_2$ (i.e., changing the roles of $x_1$ and $x_2$), I figured the lines $x_2 = x_1$ and $x_2 = -x_1$ would be relevant.]

Regarding the "usual" method of characteristic polynomial for finding the eigenvalues, I get the equation for $\det (\lambda I - H ) = 0$ of 
$$\lambda^2 - 1 = 0.$$
Did you make a computational error here?

In any event, with the correct computation, the first function is not convex.  [Geometrically, if you are familiar with convexity of one-dimensional functions, if you let $x_2 = -x_1$, you get $g(x_1) \overbrace{=}^{defined} f(x_1, -x_1) = - x_1^2$, which shows a ``concave down'' effect].

---

P.S.  Since for diagonalizable matrices (including real symmetric matrices), the determinant of the matrix is the product of the eigenvalues, and the determinant of your second matrix is 0 (I think), you should have at least one zero eigenvalue.  You should double-check that the other eigenvalue is positive.

Comment: thank you for your response. I am confused as to why my hessian was incorrect, after all is it not just
$$f_{x_1x_1},  f_{x_1x_2}$$
$$f_{x_2x_1},  f_{x_2x_2}$$

Where $f_{x_1x_1}$ would obviously yield $(x_2)' = 0$ ?
What have I done wrong, is my understanding of the definition of hessian incorrect?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @diabloescobar: your Hessian is fine, at least for the first function. Your eigenvalue computations are not.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you, I am not a smart man -_-

Comment: either could I also enquire, what is meant by the $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{++}$
My error previously was that I forgot you had to take the determinant to find the eigenvalues how silly.

Comment: What that means is that the function is defined for any real value of the first argument, but only for positive values of the second argument.