# rigorously show the given function is either convex or non convex.

Tags: convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $(x,y)\mapsto \ln(e^{x}+e^y+e^z)$. Determine whether or not $f$ is convex and rigorously justify your answer.

I am thinking this function is not convex just based on intuition.

I have taken second order partial derivative and get
$\nabla^2=\langle \dfrac{e^x+e^y}{e^x+e^y+e^z},\dfrac{e^y+e^z}{e^x+e^y+e^z},0\rangle$,

So, I believe I want to show the gradient is greater than or equal to zero to show convex,

Am I on the right path and if so what should my next step be.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calculate the Hessian matrix, you should get something like

$$
\frac{1}{\left(e^x+e^y+e^z\right)^2}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 e^x \left(e^y+e^z\right) &
   -e^{x+y} & -e^{x+z} \\
 -e^{x+y} & e^y
   \left(e^x+e^z\right) &
   -e^{y+z} \\
 -e^{x+z} & -e^{y+z} & e^z
   \left(e^x+e^y\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now, in order to hint at $f$ being convex, one needs to show that this Hessian is positive semi-definite, but to this end, it is sufficient to notice that the Hessian matrix is symmetric, has non-negative diagonal entries, and is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties).

Comment: Great, however, I'm not certain how to got the Hessian. Did it come from $\nabla^2$ that I found above, or is there a different method to calculate the Hessian matrix

Comment: by $\nabla^2$ I mean the Hessian above

Comment: I am not sure I understand the notation in your post - you can get the Hessian matrix $H_{ij}$ as $\partial^2 f /\partial x_i \partial x_j$, where, e.g., $x_1\equiv x$, $x_2\equiv y$, and $x_3\equiv z$, i.e., for example the element $(1,1)$ is $\partial^2f/\partial x \partial x$, element $(1,2)$ is $\partial^2f/\partial x \partial y$, etc.

Comment: also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720259/f-is-convex-function-iff-hessian-matrix-is-nonnegative-definite