# For which values of $a$ the function $u(x,y)=x^2+x^4+axy+y^2$ is convex? concave?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

> Consider the function
> $$
> u(x,y)=x^2+x^4+axy+y^2
> $$
> For which values of $a$ the function $u(x,y)$ is convex? concave?

I know how to solve such kind of problems for a single variable function $f(x)$. There I would have to calculate a second derivative $f''_{xx}$ and find intervals where $f''_{xx}>0$ (convex) and $f''_{xx}<0$ (concave).

But what approach should I apply here? Is it $d^2u(x,y)$ instead of $f''_{xx}$ and checking if the matrix for $d^2u(x,y)$ is positive-definite (for convex) and negative-definite (for concave)?

Comment: Positive semi-definite to be precise, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/720259/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convexness, $d^2u(x,y)$ is positively semi-definite. Concaveness is opposite.

Comment: Positive semi-definite, unless you understand “convex” as “strictly convex.”

Comment: @MartinR, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: So, in this case $u(x,y)$ is convex if $4-a^2\ge0$ and concave if $4-a^2\le0$? I just want to make sure I understood everything correctly.

Comment: And what should we say when $a=2$ or $a=-2$. In that case, $d^2u(x,y)$ is both positively and negatively semi-definite, or am I wrong about negatively semi-definite?

Comment: Did you calculate $d^2u(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, it's $\begin{pmatrix}2 & a \\a & 2\end{pmatrix}\ \ \forall x, y$. But why does it matter?

Comment: Check if $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2})\le\frac12f(x_1,y_2)+\frac12f(x_2,y_2)$ holds.